# How to change the introduction duration of an App Store subscription?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I have an App Store subscription with an introductory price with a duration of 3 days. I can see this by checking my SKProduct's introductoryPrice property, which has a subscription period of 3 days:

```
let product: SKProduct
...
print(product.introductoryPrice.subscriptionPeriod)
```

I can also check this in App Store Connect:

[image]

It says 'free for the first 3 days', but there is no way to edit that. I can only click on 'no end date' and set an end date, which is not what I want. Is that editable and if yes how?

Comment: You should create new one.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official docs on [Set an introductory offer for an auto-renewable subscription](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve1d49254f), only the end date can be edited once it's available to customers.

> Once you create an introductory price or free trial, **only the End Date of the in effect introductory offer can be edited once it's available to customers**. For future scheduled introductory offers, the start and end date can be edited. To edit the duration or price, you must create a new introductory offer.

[image]